# Create Pop-Up on camera while touching the camera using React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, camera

I'm really new with React-Native and I'm not a front-end developer. That's why I don't know if it's possible to do what I'm asking.

I saw some apps, like [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/) or [NearestWiki](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nearestwiki/id331305547?mt=8), which have like pop ups in the camera while pointing with the camera to something.

[image: NearestWiki Img]

I find it pretty amazing. I'm just wondering if it would be possible to make something like that with React-Native, but instead of giving the pop-up direct from backend, permitting that the user could "post" something and that other people that are near can see it with the camera. I mean, the user touch the screen, and can write something and when the post is saved, other people with the same app, can see the post of the first user in that place.

It would be quite funny. But I don't know if that's possible. And if that's possible, I would like to know, how.

Maybe someone knows a library or module that permits something like that. Or maybe someone can tell me how could I search for it, or give me some advice how could I start to write it.

I already solved the geolocation problem, that an user could open his camera, etc... but it remains the core, that the user could touch the screen and add a post, and then show it to other users.

I would be pretty glad if someone can at least tell me where to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience of React Native so far I would have avoided it, but it seems there's a few others that think along the same lines. There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162507/react-native-augmented-reality-ar) that has some useful info, though it's a little out of date. A quick google search for "augmented reality react native" will bring up a few handy pages like [this one.](https://blog.hellojs.org/an-augmented-reality-experiment-in-react-native-fc473f6c1b5c)

Hope that helps, please let me know if you find anything that works!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, 'cause there's no a good answer. The react-native approach are pretty bad and what I found works just for a limited number of apple chips, so not interesting for my purposes.